# Mysql query with group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
id  club_id club_option_id created
---|-------|--------------|-------
1  | 1     | 2            | 2015-02-11 16:31:23
2  | 1     | 3            | 2015-02-11 16:31:23
3  | 2     | 2            | 2015-03-06 08:16:02
```

I would like to select the club (club_id) who has both options (2 and 3)

I don't get any results with the following query:

```
SELECT club_id FROM 
club_options_to_clubs 
WHERE club_option_id = 2 AND club_option_id = 3  
GROUP BY club_id
```

How can I get club_id 1 as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below -

```
select 
t1.club_id from table_name t1
where t1.club_option_id = 2
and exits (
  select 1 from table_name t2
  where t1.club_id = t2.club_id
  and t2.club_option_id = 3
)
```

The other way is

```
select club_id from table_name
where club_option_id in (2,3)
group by club_id 
having count(*) = 2
```

With the above approach if you need to check multiple `club_option_id` pass them in the `in` function and then use the number in `having count(*) = n`
Here n = number of items in the `in` function.

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer. How would the query look if I want to check for, for example, 6 different club_option_id's?
Nesting the queries 6 times will probably give some performance problems?
This table will grow an have a lot of clubs and options linked to them.

Comment: I don't have a problem with multiple queries if that is necessary

Comment: Check the updated answer with another option of doing the same.